# iOS 8 share extension. How to make an image a requirement but text optional

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I want my share extension to show up only if an image is being shared. If text and an image is being shared it should also show up.

I had

```
NSExtensionActivationSupportsText = 1
NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount = 1
```

But then if theres only text then the share widget still appears. There has to be an image shared for my extension to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a predicate statement as explained here under ["Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html).

More information about predicate syntax can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795).

I think you want to use something like this:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
        OR ( ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.text" 
             AND ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image")
    ).@count >= 1
).@count == 1
```

Just add an NSExtensionActivationRule to your NSExtensionAttributes dictionary. Set the type to string and the value to the above SUBQUERY.